# How to send data from a form created by a plugin to an external API?

Tags: hooks, forms, api

I need to send the form data created with a plug-in to an external API, would it be the case to write a plugin for this case?
And if this type of function is viable, any tip for initiation is very valid!
I thank you all!

Comment: If you have access to the form markup, have you tried using the URL as the `action` attribute on your form?

Comment: you can grab the submitted data with `$_GET` or `$_POST` (depending on the form method) and then use `wp_remote_get` or `wp_remote_post` to send the data to the external API and get the response to process and display.

Comment: @majick
The problem is that I don't know how or on which hook I would create this function to send the data to the api, because in this case I have one or more contact forms that I need to send.
And outside I do not know when the form will be sent, because the submission is performed by a plugin
Would you have a model to be able to exemplify how I do this capture of POST data and then send it to the api?
something generic even to get the concept. Thanks.

Comment: it depends on whether you want to send the data to the API immediately (in which case you can just add an action to the `init` hook and check for specific form field values), or specifically hook into the form validation to send it after the form. in which case you would need to look into the form plugin further.

Comment: Hnnn seems that this first option would be interesting, but how could it be done?
Can you exemplify how I can do this?
let's say I have a form, but it is sent by ajax in the plugin, if I know the form id would help?
or I would have to know the inputs name of each form, an example would be very useful for me, I thank you in advance!